# Calabash directory structure for testing both Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, directory-structure, calabash

This is the current structure for the automation test.

- automationRepo

  - Docs
  - features

    - support

      - framework
    - step_definitions

      - config
      - lib
    - featurefile.feature
  - logs

With the support directory I have support files which run for Android.
What I've done to make this run on iOS is replace with the iOS support files.

Question is how can I choose to run iOS or Android without having switching the support files over.

I tried this:

- automationRepo

  - Docs
  - features

    - support (iOS / android)

      - framework
    - step_definitions

      - config
      - lib
    - featurefiles

      - featurefile.feature
  - logs
  - android

    - support (android)

      - framework
    - step_definitions (symlink)
    - featurefiles (symlink)
  - iOS

    - support (iOS)

      - framework
    - step_definitions (symlink)
    - featurefiles (symlink)

This didn't work because the featurefile needed to be at a higher level than step_definitions, or at least that what appeared to be the problem.

Has anyone else managed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature file should be in your feature folder's root alongside **android** and **ios** folders.

```
- automationRepo
 - feature
   - android (folder)
   - ios (folder)
   - step_definitions (folder)
   - support (folder)
   - your_feature_file.feature
```

PS: I'm using a BDD framework named **sunomono** (https://rubygems.org/gems/sunomono), previously named **cs-bdd** to generate a directory structure and write calabash tests using Screen Objects design patterns. It's a easier way!

Comment: Thanks for your response, what do you have in your iOS and Android directories?

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response! My Android/iOS directories has the same estructure: 

* features 
* modules 
* screens 
* step_definitions 
* support